# Information (datasheet) about stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, datasheet

I've got stepper motor from a friend. But unfortunately, neither my friend or I know what kind of stepper motor it is, how much current it needs and on what voltage it operates.

Do you have any idea how I could find something about that stepper motor ? Maybe datasheet ? Anyway, here are pictures ... I think that at least someone experienced could tell me something about it based on the wires :)

[image: Stepper1]
[image: Stepper2]
[image: Stepper3]

Thanks !!

Comment: Any progress with getting this thing to work?

Comment: Unfortunately no ... But I haven't had enough free time to experiment with it ...

Comment: Okay, Good luck!

Comment: the brown wires are the center tab where you feed the probably 12v (i tested with 5v), using the following circuit with an arduino and the basic stepper demo, the cable sequence is white, red, orange, blue. the motor has 48 steps, so 7.5deg per step.i used the uln2803 darlington array to test the motor. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/218518/76228

Comment: But i don't know for sure if it's 12v and how many Amps it needs. Looking at the driver used it prolly needs less than 2Amps but the voltage could be 24v. http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/sma6511_ds_en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to be an Epson stepper motor with the model EM-199, I have one that looks similar, and has the model EM-437, but mine is sitting unused because I cant find any documentation either.

UPDATE:
I just found something that may help you out. This is a comment from http://www.instructables.com/answers/How-can-I-use-a-stepper-motor-that-has-no-markings/

First you need to know how to wire it, for instruction on that go to http://www.piclist.com/techref/io/stepper/wires.htm 
To find the rated amperage you would need to take it apart then use a micrometer or Caliper to find the coil wire diameter (note: a ruler is not accurate enough) once you have the wire diameter change the measurement to inches in Decimal Value then multiply it by 100 then you have the amp rating. To find the voltage you need a ohm meter to find the ohm value then multiply ohms by the amps to find the volts rating. To find the rotation degrees then you need a controller to test this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks ;) But I'm stuck on first step :D Can you give me any tips how to take it apart ?

Comment: Well, that depends on how it was put together. If it has little tabs, use a dremmel to remove them, if it is welded together, well, good luck... They typically have screws, and you should be able to get them out fairly easily. Sometimes the screws are concealed under stickers, and other removable parts of the motor, so just try taking everything apart, and you should find your answer.

Comment: The circuit board, and the plastic piece on the back (it looks like it has an allen wrench screw on it) may be a good place to start.

Comment: Good luck. Keep me updated when you finish. I want to be able to do this to mine(when I get back to my shop).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pump motor]

Type: 4-phase 48-pole PM type stepping motor
Drive voltage: 42 V DC ± 5%
Winding resistance: 10.3 Ohms ± 10% (per phase 25Cº)